# SonarQube - java/groovy multimodule project scan

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have:

- SonarQube v5.6 + Groovy plugin
- gradle 3.5
- org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5

Configuration:

```
def sourceProjects = allprojects.findAll { it.file('src/main').exists() }
configure(sourceProjects) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
    sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/groovy']

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile lib.groovy_core
    }
}
```

Project structure:

- rootDir

  - apps

    - app-backend
    - app-ui
  - modules

    - module 1
    - module 2
    - module 3

Whenever I run: `$ ./gradlew sonarqube` what happens is when it goes through different modules, it does not aggregate sonar reports. It throws in last module scan and overwrites anything that was already stored. So after running this, I just get the results for last modules that gradle executor processed. Can something be done about that?

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth I solved this issue by applying sonar cube to the root project only:

```
project(':') {
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
}
```